# left aligning the following Cauchy Problem or a matrix in Latex

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have trouble left aligning the following Cauchy Problem:

```
$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
x' (t) = sin ( x(t)), t\in \mathbb{R}\\ 
x(0)=x_0
\end{matrix}\right.
$
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could employ the `cases` environment that's provided by the `amsmath` package. Alternatively, you could use an `array` environment with a single `l`-type column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' environment
\usepackage{amssymb} % for '\mathbb' macro
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{cases}
x'(t) = \sin x(t), & t\in\mathbb{R}\\ 
x(0)=x_0
\end{cases} 
\quad
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}l}
x'(t) = \sin x(t),\ t\in\mathbb{R}\\ 
x(0)=x_0
\end{array}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```